# Convert to CSS3 Gradient

Tags: html, css, gradient

I am new to using CSS3 (specially gradients). How do I convert the following HTML/CSS coded border to one with CSS3-based gradient (i.e. using no image)

I want to convert **FROM**

[image: Normal]
Normal CSS border/background color

**TO**

[image]
Box with Gradient

Width/Heights are approx in the img above...I need to know how to get the gradient as per the 2nd fig ?

Comment: It might be helfpul if you included the actual CSS in your question, rather than just the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the colors you are working with, you want to do something like this

```
.class{
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#000));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #000);
}
```

Here's a tool that might help:

http://gradients.glrzad.com/

Answer (score 3):

[This link](http://css3please.com/) should help you. You will find the syntax for gradients there.

It's this one for all the major browsers:

```
  background-color: #444444;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444444), to(#999999)); 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); 
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); 
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); 
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); 
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #444444, #999999);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#444444', EndColorStr='#999999');
```

…while `#444444` is the color at top of the gradient and `#999999` the gradient-color at the bottom.

The different "vendor-prefixes" ensure that the gradient works in different browsers as the 'default'-syntax is not supported by every browser by now.
The `filter`-property will make the gradient work in Internet Explorer 8 and below. But this has some drawbacks (performance aso…). Just use it if really necessary.

**Edit:** The syntax for linear-gradient changed. The spec'd syntax:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #444444, #999999);
```

I've changed this above too, so everyone can just copy this.

Comment: Thanks @Phrogz for removing the typo :)

Comment: +1 for the most complete answer. In addition, it's worth noting the existence of [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) which adds support for the standard CSS to IE, instead of having to use that horrible `filter` style.

Comment: Whay do you feel or say that the filter style is horrible ?

Comment: It's not pretty performant. It can also lead into problems, when using it in connection with border-radius and all that stuff.

Comment: FWIW the linear-gradient syntax changed a while ago. `top` is now `to bottom`.

Answer (score 0):

The Best place to look is below:

[CSS3 Gradients](http://css3.mikeplate.com)

Answer (score 0):

CSS gradients are cool stuff. **But you have one problem**. When you are used background gradients in ie9. You can not used border radius are other CSS3. The background filter propertiy for ie is suck. I have a better solution for this. That fix the problem in ie9.

With this tool you create a gradient: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/
And with this tool you create a SVG for ie9: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/svggradientbackgroundmaker/default.html

Now we have this code:

```
background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxIDEiIHByZXNlcnZlQXNwZWN0UmF0aW89Im5vbmUiPgo8bGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQgaWQ9Imc1OCIgZ3JhZGllbnRVbml0cz0idXNlclNwYWNlT25Vc2UiIHgxPSIwJSIgeTE9IjAlIiB4Mj0iMTAwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgo8c3RvcCBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjNDQ0NDQ0IiBvZmZzZXQ9IjAiLz48c3RvcCBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjOTk5OTk5IiBvZmZzZXQ9IjEiLz4KPC9saW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudD4KPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNnNTgpIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=);
background: #444444; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444 0%, #999999 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#444444), color-stop(100%,#999999)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444444 0%,#999999 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #444444 0%,#999999 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #444444 0%,#999999 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top, #444444 0%,#999999 100%); /* W3C */
```